# Configuring a Search Results Web Part to use a new result source does not displays results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I used this [**link**](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tothesharepoint/2013/11/04/how-to-configure-the-search-results-web-part-to-use-a-new-result-source-in-sharepoint-2013/) to create a **Search Results WebPart**. When I do a search I see a line that displays "5 results" within the Search Results WebPart but my 5 items do not display. I believe my issue is I created a brand new page on my sub-site and added the search webpart to this new page.

From doing some research it seems like I may need to add the webpart on the site collections search results page and not a brand new page?  My hesitation is my objective was to accomplish 2 searches on a particular sub-site and NOT the site collection.

The 2 searches I wanted:

1. I wanted to have all documents found in the sub-site (Marketing) library as a search container
2. I wanted to have all documents found in all lists (not libraries) as a second search container for the sub-site (Marketing).

I do not want to touch the search results page on the site collection if possible.

Where I am really confused is if I set up several new result sources via manage result sources how do I leverage these new result sources ?  Do I need to create a WebPart for each new result source within the Site Collection results page.

Comment: As per your requirement, you can have Search Center sites created for each site collection in your SP webappln.So, you can create a single page in this search center having search results web part added or you can add the web part in the existing results.aspx page as well. The link you have provided everything related to search results.So go for a deep dive into Bella_Engen's blog series,you will find the solution. Also you can create your result sources at the sub-site level too.

Comment: a similar question have asked https://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/233982 for SPO, you can apply the same in sp on-premises too.